# I've a (single)tree of categories and subcategories, now I want to add items in it as treeNode

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, treenode

I don't know how to traverse my tree of categories and subcategories so that I can find specific subcategory to make root of items.
I want to know how to traverse a (single)Tree of TreeNodes, which I've made by a simple foreach loop, by putting each subcategory as child of it's respective category.

There is no built-in methods in treeNode about how can we get to all subcategories or their names or data or anything except one child.

My method to create 5-level treeNode structure, as it's a business rule to define 5 levels of subcategories of a category.

```
public TreeNode findCategoryNode(Category category) {
        TreeNode categoryNode = new DefaultTreeNode(category, null);
        for(TreeNode tn : root.getChildren()) {
            if(tn.equals(categoryNode))
                return categoryNode;
        }
        return new DefaultTreeNode(CategoryLocalServiceUtil.getInstance());
    }
```

how can I get my specific subcategory, by traversing this single node of tree.

Comment: What did you try so far and what is your expected/observed in-/output of your algorithm?

Comment: this works fine so far to create root of all categories and subs, but I dont find yet any method to traverse my this root so that I can further make it "root" for items.

Comment: I simply asking for a solution, to get a specific node of my own choice

Comment: I've tried this but equals method doesn't give required treenode

Comment: I've made a TreeNode of my specific category and then iterate it with root which is made by uper method, but "equals" method returns nothing when two objects are compared in foreach loop

Comment: You can [edit](//stackoverflow.com/posts/58796916/edit) your post and add your attempted method.

Comment: Compare with the content of the treenode... The treenode itself is just a container

Comment: I've edited post, I'm unable to get to the contents, how can I?

Comment: Start by looking at the api of TreeNode or DefaultTreeNode... and try... There is no attempt in your code.

Comment: I was actually getting root children only by getChildren(), to go deeper I've to make another loop in existing, likewise in creating the root but thanks for your help.

Comment: But still, creating a TreeNode with your category and compare that is the wrong way to go... Compare the data in the treenodes

Comment: OK, thanks for suggestion